# Making Tic-Tac-Toe winning check more efficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

My code works perfectly fine and I would just like to clean it up a little. From the research I've done, I cannot find anyone that used a multidimensional list to a game of TTT. I'm just looking for a way to make this code prettier than it is right now.

```
grid = [['-','-','-'],
       ['-','-','-'],
       ['-','-','-']]
turn = 'x'
stl = True
print("Please use this format: row/col")
rounds = 0

def printGrid(grid):
    for i,j,k in grid:
        b = print(i,j,k)

def place(grid,turn,row,col):
    if grid[row][col] == '-':
        grid[row][col] = turn
        return True

    else:
        print("Please select an untaken postion\n")
        return False

while stl:
    rounds += 1
    print("Round %i!" % rounds)

    try:

        printGrid(grid)
        print("\nIt is %s's turn.\n" % turn)
        inp = input("What position do you want to place your symbol? (row/col 1-3/1-3) ")
        row,col = inp.split('/')
        row = int(row)-1
        col = int(col)-1
        print()

        a = place(grid,turn,row,col)

        if a == True:
            if turn == 'x':
                turn = 'o'
            else:turn = 'x'

    except(IndexError,ValueError):print("\nPlease select a viable position.\n")

    print('----------------------------------\n')

    if ['x','x','x'] in grid:
        print("X Victory! You won in %i rounds!\n" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
    elif ['o','o','o'] in grid:
        print("O Victory! You won in %i rounds!\n" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False

    if grid[0][0] == 'x' and grid[1][0] == 'x' and grid[2][0] == 'x':
        print("X Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
    elif grid[0][1] == 'x' and grid[1][1] == 'x' and grid[2][1] == 'x':
        print("X Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
    elif grid[0][2] == 'x' and grid[1][2] == 'x' and grid[2][2] == 'x':
        print("X Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
    elif grid[0][0] == 'x' and grid[1][1] == 'x' and grid[2][2] == 'x':
        print("X Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
    elif grid[0][2] == 'x' and grid[1][1] == 'x' and grid[2][0] == 'x':
        print("X Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False

    elif grid[0][0] == 'o' and grid[1][0] == 'o' and grid[2][0] == 'o':
        print("O Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
    elif grid[0][1] == 'o' and grid[1][1] == 'o' and grid[2][1] == 'o':
        print("O Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
    elif grid[0][2] == 'o' and grid[1][2] == 'o' and grid[2][2] == 'o':
        print("O Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
    elif grid[0][0] == 'o' and grid[1][1] == 'o' and grid[2][2] == 'o':
        print("O Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
    elif grid[0][2] == 'o' and grid[1][1] == 'o' and grid[2][0] == 'o':
        print("O Victory! You won in %i rounds!" % rounds)
        printGrid(grid)
        stl = False
```

As you can see, the last portion of the code is gross. I would just like to see if there is a better way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the winning positions as follows:

```
winning = [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)],
           [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)],
           [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)], 
           ...]
```

Now you can much more easily loop through the positions and test them, using `all`:

```
for positions in winning:
    for symbol in 'xy':
        if all(grid[r][c] == symbol for r, c in positions):
            print("{} Victory! You won in {} rounds!".format(symbol.upper(), 
                                                             rounds)
            stl = False
            break
```

I would wrap all of this in a class, to make life a bit easier:

```
class TicTacToe:

    BLANK = '-'

    WINNING = [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)],
               [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)],
               [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)], 
               ...]

    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = [[self.BLANK for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join([' '.join(row) for row in self.grid])

    def won(self):
        """Return the winning symbol, or None if not yet won."""
        for positions in self.WINNING:
            for symbol in 'xy':
                if all(self.grid[r][c] == symbol for r, c in positions):
                    return symbol

   def make_move(self, symbol, row, col):
       if self.grid[row][col] != self.BLANK:
           raise ValueError("Position already occupied.")
       self.grid[row][col] = symbol

   ...
```

---

In terms of general code review, note that:

1. You should not have multiple statements on the same line (e.g. `else:turn = 'x'`);
2. The [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) includes guidance on whitespace (e.g. see the spaces after commas in the code I have posted);
3. There's no need to assign the result of `print` - it is `None`, just `print(i,j,k)`;
4. You should not have code just running within the script, write a `main` function and guard a call to it behind `if __name__ == '__main__':`; and
5. You should generally have more, smaller blocks of functionality (e.g. you could have a function whose job is to get the user to input a valid `row/col` selection).